# How to Debounce with Observer Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, debouncing

I am trying to run `getResponse` once when a web components finishes loading.  However, when I try to run this, the `debounce` function just acts as an async delay and runs 4 times after 5000 ms.

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    procedure: {
      type: String,
      observer: 'debounce'
    }
  }
}

debounce() {
  this._debouncer = Polymer.Debouncer.debounce(this._debouncer, Polymer.Async.timeOut.after(5000), () => {
    this.getResponse();
  });
}

getResponse() {
  console.log('get resp');
}
```

What is necessary to get `getResponse` to run once upon the loading of the element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Run Function Once On Load (then by Observer) in Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992723/how-to-run-function-once-on-load-then-by-observer-in-polymer)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use a debouncer for that? you could just use the connectedCallBack to get a one Time Event

```js
class DemoElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.callStack = 'constructor->';
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.callStack += 'connectedCallback';
    console.log('rendered');
    fetch(this.fakeAjax()).then((response) => {
      // can't do real ajax request here so we fake it... normally you would do 
      // something like this.innerHTML = response.text();
      // not that "rendered" get console logged before "fetch done"
      this.innerHTML = `
        <p>${this.callStack}</p>
        <p>${response.statusText}</p>
      `;
      console.log('fetch done');
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err); // Error :(
    });
  }
  
  fakeAjax() {
    return window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['empty']));
  };
}
customElements.define('demo-element', DemoElement);
```

```html
<demo-element></demo-element>
```

If you really need to use an observer you could also set a flag `this.isLoaded` in your `connectedCallback()` and check for that in your observer code.

Comment: Using this method, an AJAX call was run before the `<iron-ajax>` component loaded, throwing an error.

Comment: that seems strange? how are you creating the iron-ajax? maybe try using just fetch... on timing issues it is usually easier to handle than bringing a webcomponent into the mix...

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?  I'm not familiar with `fetch`.

Comment: I'm not seeing the advantage over a working debounce function.  This solution seems a bit convoluted..